# Error: Could not find or load main class Check.java

Tags: java, command-line

I have `Check` class in my `ua.kiev.prog` package.

It is `Check`class :

```
package main.java.ua.kiev.prog;
public class Check {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");}
}
```

I need to run program from console and I am trying in console :

```
C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\CHECK\src\main\java\ua\kiev\prog>javac Check.java
```

And when I am trying to run :

```
C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\CHECK\src\main\java\ua\kiev\prog>java Check.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Check.java
```

In my system variables I have :

CLASSPATH : D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\lib

PATH : D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

Appreciate for each help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (qualified) name of your class is `main.java.ua.kiev.prog.Check`, not `Check.java`, so use `java main.java.ua.kiev.prog.Check` instead. The `java` command doesn't and cannot do anything with source files.

Make sure you're running from `C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\CHECK\src`

Comment: I tried `java Check` , it has the same error

Comment: @user13566239 I updated it - I forgot that your class was inside a package. You must use the qualified name to run it.

Comment: `java main.java.ua.kiev.prog.Check`also doesn't work and has the same error

Comment: cd to `C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\CHECK\src` and run from there